# IOS WKWebView and UIWebView isn't loading JavaScript Sign Up form while Safari does

Tags: javascript, ios, swift3, safari, uiwebview

In Safari my Sign Up form JavaScript code  works fine, but in UIWebView and in WKWebView that form isn't loading.

Here is my Code to review.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var Webview: UIWebView!

var webView: WKWebView!
var websites = ["lampecompany.com", "lampecompany.com"]

override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://" + websites[0])!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url) as URLRequest)
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

}
```

Main page opens correctly and then Menu -> Apply,  on this screen Apply here form doesn't display.

Here are both screenshots attached. Safari and WKWebView.

[image] 
[image]

Any help regarding this that my WKWebView start behaving like Safari and open each and everything correctly as Safari browser does.

When I put my website link here in this WKWebView browser then its working. 
https://github.com/mbarnig/WKWebView

so why not in my code. I used the same code in my app but in vein.

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your web page Signup form ([iframe](https://www.lampeplacementservices.com/LampeOptin/LampeOptinReferralForm.html)) has SSL issue.

In iOS, If you are loading an http url, then you have to add `App Transport Security Settings` in your `info.plist` file.

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

I found the issue in the following way.

1. Enable Safari Developer mode Safari-> Preference -> Advanced -> Show
   Developer option on Menu.
2. Run your app on simulator and Open Safari
   browser on your Mac.
3. Go to Developer menu -> Simulator -> Select
   your site url.
4. You will get the console log of your web page.

Please see your web page console log below.

[image]

**Error : Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to** https://www.lampeplacementservices.com/LampeOptin/LampeOptinReferralForm.html

Comment: Thank You! I added transport security Settings and Allow arbitrary loads YES then this worked fine for me.

Comment: Just as an additional heads-up: If you know the actual URL you need to access without SSL and can't fix the certificate you can (and probably should) not just allow arbitrary loads, but set up your info plist to only allow an exception for this specific URL, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33 Apple might become stricter in enforcing ATS and require you to provide a reason for NSArbitraryLoads in the future (when submitting your app for review, I mean). :)